# Where do NGU, R2D2, MuZero and Agent57 fit on the Taxonomy of Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

OpenAI has a great Taxonomy of Reinforcement Learning Algorithms. I was wondering where the following papers would go on this tree?

1. [Never Give Up](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06038)
2. [Agent57](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.13350)
3. [MuZero](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.08265)
4. [R2D2](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=r1lyTjAqYX)

[image: A Taxonomy of RL Algorithms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making an RL taxonomy [1] and recently had to answer this question myself. Here's my take on it.

- Agent57 is based on NGU, which in turn is based on R2D2, which stands for Recurrent Replay Distributed DQN. So they're all Q-learning, model-free RL.
- MuZero is model-based and it's learning the model. This is stated in the paper (page 2, first statement) and mentioned in Agent57 paper as well.

[1] https://github.com/bennylp/RL-Taxonomy